# UI freezing while showing image into ImageView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

Inside my `RecyclerView`'s row I have an `ImageView` and I want to preview this `ImageView`'s  image on the same activity (full screen preview)

and for that I'm doing this:

```
public void showImageZoomable(String imageURL) {

imageViewZoomable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisk(true).build();

imageLoader.loadImage(imageURL , options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

        imageViewZoomable.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(loadedImage));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

    }
});
toolBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

}

the above function gets triggered when user taps on `ImageView` (which is on `Recyclerview`'s row) and it takes the url of that image (image is already cached)
and assigns it to `imageViewZoomable`  using [imageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library

it works fine but the whole process is bit slow and laggy

any idea how can I improve it?? or the way I'm doing it is not efficient then please suggest me a better alternative

Comment: 1. You should declare the ImageLoader and DisplayImageOptions instance only once.
2. Using loadImage and declare DisplayImageOptions on Recyclerview's row (viewHolder adapter) make the RecyclerView run slowly. If you can't use `displayImage` of imageLoader, You can try other libraries like `Picasso` or `Glide`,.. etc

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
  imageLoader.displayImage(imageURL, imageViewZoomable);
```

instead of

```
  imageLoader.loadImage(...);
```

Comment: thanks for responding ,  i can't use `displayImage ` because `imageViewZoomable` is not  an imageView (an extended imageView class) and `displayImage` requires an imageView as parameter

Answer (score 0):

U can use a fullscreen dialog (extends DialogFragment) to show a fullscreen image when user clicks the image in recyclerview item

Comment: image is on recyclerView's item and i wanna show it on parent's layout , can we do that ? how ?

Comment: Create the imageview in the parent layout file & make it visible when showing images & set visibility gone when you want to close the image. But it's not a good way to do it. If you use a fullscreen dialog, it overlays above the recyclerview & when user click back, it dismisses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code if your custom class return imageView Object like imageViewZoomable.getImage() as a imageView so you can pass it like below.

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageURL, imageViewZoomable.getImage());
```